# Помещение объекта в контейнер и удаление из него

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется код, который осуществляет анимацию.При помещении "груз" в "блок1", "груз" становился дочерним по отношению к "блок1" ("блок1" - родитель). При нажатии кнопки "старт" осуществляется движение "блока1" совместно с "грузом." Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "сначало" груз, который был помещен в блок, возвращался на свое прежнее место??? И как можно упростить функции помещения в контейнер?

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $(".item").draggable({
     revert: true
   });


   var angle = 0;
   $("#start").click(function() {

     $("#lineP").animate({
       height: 440
     }, 1000);
     $("#lineL").animate({
       height: 130
     }, 1000);
     $("#gruzL").animate({
       top: 208
     }, 1000);
     $("#gruzP").animate({
       top: 518
     }, 1000);

   });

   $("#stop").click(function() {
     $("#lineL").stop();
     $("#lineP").stop();
     $("#gruzL").stop();
     $("#gruzP").stop();
   });

   $("#nachalo").click(function() {
     $("#lineL").css({
       height: 440
     });
     $("#lineP").css({
       height: 130
     });
     $("#gruzL").css({
       top: 210,
       left: 215
     });
     $("#gruzP").css({
       top: 520,
       left: 93
     });
     $("#gruzP").empty();

   });



   var cord1 = $("#gruzP").position();
   xpos1 = cord1.left;
   ypos1 = cord1.top;
   $("#gr1").mouseup(function() {
     var xpos, ypos;
     var cord = $("#gr1").position();
     xpos = cord.left;
     ypos = cord.top;
     console.log(xpos + " " + ypos);
     if (xpos + 30 >= xpos1 && xpos <= xpos1 + 30 && ypos <= ypos1 + 50) {
       alert("попадает");
       $("#gr1").appendTo("#gruzP");
       $("#gr1").draggable({
         revert: false
       });
       $("#gr1").css({
         top: -7,
         left: -1
       });
     } else {
       alert("не попадает");
     }
   });

   $("#gr2").mouseup(function() {
     var xpos, ypos;
     var cord = $("#gr2").position();
     xpos = cord.left;
     ypos = cord.top;
     if (xpos + 30 >= xpos1 && xpos <= xpos1 + 30 && ypos <= ypos1 + 50) {
       alert("попадает");
       $("#gr2").appendTo("#gruzP");
       $("#gr2").draggable({
         revert: false
       });
       $("#gr2").css({
         top: -12,
         left: -1
       });
     } else {
       alert("не попадает");
     }
   });

   $("#gr3").mouseup(function() {
     var xpos, ypos;
     var cord = $("#gr3").position();
     xpos = cord.left;
     ypos = cord.top;
     if (xpos + 30 >= xpos1 && xpos <= xpos1 + 30 && ypos <= ypos1 + 50) {
       alert("попадает");
       $("#gr3").appendTo("#gruzP")
       $("#gr3").draggable({
         revert: false
       });
       $("#gr3").css({
         top: -20,
         left: -1
       });
     } else {
       alert("не попадает");
     }
   });

   $("#gr4").mouseup(function() {
     var xpos, ypos;
     var cord = $("#gr4").position();
     xpos = cord.left;
     ypos = cord.top;
     if (xpos + 30 >= xpos1 && xpos <= xpos1 + 30 && ypos <= ypos1 + 50) {
       alert("попадает");
       $("#gr4").appendTo("#gruzP")
       $("#gr4").draggable({
         revert: false
       });
       $("#gr4").css({
         top: -25,
         left: -1
       });
     } else {
       alert("не попадает");
     }
   });

 });
```

```css
 #gruz_container {

   position: absolute;

   left: 370px;

   top: 180px;

   width: 260px;

   height: 60px;

 }

 #gr1 {

   position: absolute;

   left: 375px;

   top: 223px;

   height: 7px;

   width: 30px;

   border: 1px solid black;

   background: linear-gradient(to left, #666666, #CCCCCC 75%, #333333);

 }

 #gr2 {

   position: absolute;

   left: 445px;

   top: 218px;

   height: 12px;

   width: 30px;

   border: 1px solid black;

   background: linear-gradient(to left, #666666, #CCCCCC 75%, #333333);

 }

 #gr3 {

   position: absolute;

   left: 515px;

   top: 210px;

   height: 20px;

   width: 30px;

   border: 1px solid black;

   background: linear-gradient(to left, #666666, #CCCCCC 75%, #333333);

 }

 #gr4 {

   position: absolute;

   left: 590px;

   top: 205px;

   height: 25px;

   width: 30px;

   border: 1px solid black;

   background: linear-gradient(to left, #666666, #CCCCCC 75%, #333333);

 }

 .item {

   background: linear-gradient(to left, #666666, #CCCCCC 75%, #333333);

 }

 #lineL {

   position: absolute;

   top: 80px;

   left: 105px;

   width: 2px;

   height: 440px;

   background-color: black;

 }

 #lineP {

   position: absolute;

   top: 80px;

   left: 230px;

   width: 2px;

   height: 130px;

   background-color: black;

 }

 #gruzL {

   position: absolute;

   border: 1px solid black;

   top: 520px;

   left: 93px;

   width: 30px;

   height: 50px;

   background-color: yellow;

   background: linear-gradient(to left, #666666, #CCCCCC 75%, #333333);

 }

 #gruzP {

   position: absolute;

   border: 1px solid black;

   top: 210px;

   left: 215px;

   width: 30px;

   height: 50px;

   background-color: yellow;

   background: linear-gradient(to left, #666666, #CCCCCC 75%, #333333);

 }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="lineL"></div>
<div id="lineP"></div>



<div id="gruzL">Блок2</div>
<div id="gruzP">Блок1</div>
<div class="item" id="gr1">
  <label class="price">2.5</label>
</div>
<div class="item" id="gr2">
  <label class="price">5</label>
</div>
<div class="item" id="gr3">
  <label class="price">8</label>
</div>
<div class="item" id="gr4">
  <label class="price">10</label>
</div>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<button id="nachalo">Сначала</button>
```

Comment: Похоже, что это вопрос _как-то связан_ с http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442282/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: да, он связан с ним. Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Сначала" все объекты возвращались на свои прежние  места?

Answer (score 1):

Вот код для функции клика "Сначала":

```
$("#nachalo").click(function() {
    $("#lineL, #lineP, #gruzL, #gruzP, .item").removeAttr('style'); //очищаем стили 
    $("#gruzP").children("div.item").insertAfter( "#gruzP" ); //достаем все из контейнера и помещаем на место
});
```